# Sorting objects by similarity with linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have created a program that processes data based on a sorted List of ObjectProperties, one of these properties is List of strings. Right now, elements can be sorted based on simple properties like size and rate, but I'd like to be able to sort subsort by List of strings similarity. In other words, I'd like to sort by size, then rate, then the similarity of the List of strings.

```
lMessages.OrderBy(x => x.Size).ThenBy(x => x.Rate).ThenBy(???)
```

I can calculate the similarity pretty easily:

```
private double FindExactMatrixSimilarity(List<string> A, List<string> B)
{
    var lSimilarity = A.Intersect(B);
    var lUnion = A.Union(B);

    if (lUnion.Count() == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return Convert.ToDouble(lSimilarity.Count()) / Convert.ToDouble(lUnion.Count());
}
```

I'm getting stuck figuring out how to use this information. It seems like it needs an initial condition. If I know the first object, I can sort just fine. It won't be deterministic, but I don't care. If I want to sort by size, then rate, and then similarity, I don't think I know which object is first in my little group where the sizes and rates match. Am I over-complicating this?

Comment: Do you understand the reason why you cannot sort by equality? The reason why you cannot sort by similarity is exactly the same: the relationship is *symmetric*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, here's a way I think should work for you when you calculate the similarity based on the first element in each group of messages that has the same size and rate. It's not beautiful, it's not a single Linq statement, but it should work.

I split it into more single commands than necessary for better understanding.

```
List<Message> finalList = new List<Message>();

// First, group all elements with similar size and rate
var groupedMessages = orderedMessages.GroupBy(m => new { m.Size, m.Rate });

// Now bring them into the correct order by their size and rate
groupedMessages = groupedMessages.OrderBy(gm => gm.Key.Rate).ThenBy(gm => gm.Key.Size);

// Now sort by similarity within each group
foreach (var gm in groupedMessages)
{
    List<string> baseStringList = gm.First().StringList;

    var orderedGroupEntries = gm.OrderByDescending(
        m => FindExactMatrixSimilarity(baseStringList, m.StringList));

    // This will add to the result list in the correct order
    finalList.AddRange(orderedGroupEntries);
}
```

**Edit**: Here's a LINQ only version:

```
var result = (from m in messageList
              group m by new
              {
                  m.Rate,
                  m.Size
              } into groupedMessages
              orderby groupedMessages.Key.Rate, groupedMessages.Key.Size
              select new List<Message>(
                  from m in groupedMessages
                  let baseStringList = groupedMessages.First().StringList
                  orderby FindExactMatrixSimilarity(baseStringList, m.StringList) descending
                  select m)
              ).SelectMany(m => m);
```

Comment: It should be IComparer<string>

Comment: @CSharpie Actually, it should be IComparer<List<string>>, but thanks for your hint. :) I also forgot the class keyword. I'm so bad with brian compiled code :)

Comment: This code looks syntactically sound, but what would it do? Wouldn't this just identify that A is more similar to A than B? I really need it to state that B is more similar to A than C.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood what you really asked for. But I'm still not entirely sure how your similarity ordering should work: do you want to sort elements only by their similarity to their direct neighbors in the list (which won't work by doing a order by) or do you want to sort them by each's elements similarity to the top (?) element of a group of items with the same size and rate?

Comment: I think for my purposes, either would be fine. If I compare each element to the top or each element to its neighbor -- I think the difference should be negligible. I'd prefer to compare each element to the top, but at this point, I'll take what I can get.

Comment: I updated the answer, hope it's what you are looking for. Or do you really want it in one single Linq statement?

Comment: Ok I also added a LINQ only version now because we all hate to use foreach :)

Comment: This looks perfect! Thanks!